# Java SAX parsing. Getting access to file lines in the currently parsing xml file

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

When parsing an XML document, you can set a locator, the locator will tell you what current line and column number your are currently on when different events fire.

I am wondering, how can I get the contents of the line, do I have to pass the file, read it into an array myself, isn't this already done by the sax handler, since it is giving me access to the locator, there has to be away to also access the file that the handler is currently working with.

Thanks!

::::::::::::::::::::::::::EDIT:::::::::::::::::::

I am trying to echo an xml file and want doctype declarations to be included:

```
<!DOCTYPE employee [<!ELEMENT employee (Name, Dept, Title)>
<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)> 
<!ELEMENT Dept (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)> ]>
```

There is a

```
public void startDTD(String name, String publicId, String systemId);
```

and a

```
public void endDTD();
```

Where you can use the locator to get current line and column, and read from file.

There are a couple of things that the SAX parser does not fire events on or give sufficient information as to what was in the read XML file.

Comment: Do you find any clean solution for this problem?

Comment: @Kakawait Wow, that was long time ago! However, I believe my EDIT contains the answer. I remember that the first line however is not always available.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, ar you sure the parser doesn't provide the information you need via one of the more specialized handlers, e.g. LexicalHandler?

If you really need access to the raw data, write a Reader or InputStream implementation that sits between the SAX parser and the "real" Reader or InputStream, passing all read() requests on to the underlying reader, but keeping track of the last few lines read from the file. This filter can then respond to requests to provide the content of line N, because it has retained the data. However, I'm not sure how you can make this work to meet your real requirement, because the information you are looking for can be spread over an arbitrary number of lines.

Comment: No, I am extending DefaultHandler2 which implements LexicalHandler, and I have added all possible methods to my handler and sysout the method name for all and there is none called with any useful information. I like the way you are thinking, when it comes to the InputStream implementation :) That's clever, but cannot really find the spot where things are actually read. I could extend inputstream and re-implement read(), however it is read as bytes, one would also have to convert the bytes properly into chars and newlines, but doable.. there should be a class to turn a byte into a char, I hope!

Comment: Hmm... FileInputStream extends InputStream, so I would have to create a FileInputStream class as well that extends mine, and that would probably be a full implementation, as I cannot extend the original FileInputStream and then extend my InputStream. Perhaps the delegate pattern might simplyfy but still, it doesnt feel too sexy..

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get to the "file". There might not even be a file since the output could be generated dynamically or fetched over the network. What the parser does is keep track of the number of newlines (\r\n, \n or \r) it has passed while parsing the content. When using SAX not all of the current line is necessarily available (imagine a large document, all on one line).

You could wrap your input in a class which keeps track of the "current line" for you, but again, beware of large documents on a single line.

EDIT: The promised simple wrapper

```
public class LastLineInputStreamWrapper extends InputStream {

    private final byte[] buffer = new byte[10*1024];
    private final InputStream wrapped;
    private int previous;
    private int length;

    public LastLineInputStreamWrapper(InputStream wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int current = wrapped.read();
        if ('\r' == current) {
            newLine();
        } else if ('\n' == current) {
            if ('\r' != previous) {
                newLine();
            }
        } else {
            add(current);
        }
        previous = current;
        return current;
    }

    private void newLine() {
        length = 0;
    }

    private void add(int current) {
        if (length < buffer.length && current != -1) {
            buffer[length++] = (byte) current;
        }
    }

    public byte[] getLine() {
        byte[] line = new byte[length];
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, line, 0, length);
        return line;
    }
}
```

A simple way of doing it, just to show you how to get started. If you want to go down this route you probably want to override the read(byte[]) methods to avoid calling read for each byte.

If you instead have a Reader, then you can use characters directly instead of bytes.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The reason I need this is that I am trying to output the <!DOCTYPE content ... see my edited question for a bit more details... I cannot find a way to do this without having access to the file.

Comment: @Hamidam How does your parser get access to the file? Through a file name, an input stream or something else? I'll update the answer of how to wrap an input stream to "remember" last line.

Comment: A @Roger Hej förresten! :) ... se min kommentar för Michael :)